# Object Detection App using Flutter technology not showing Correct Object names

Tags: flutter, object, detection

My project is Object detection app using Flutter technology and dart. I have trained my Dataset in a way that...I have created my Own dataset and then trained using The Google teachable machine using TensorFlow lite
app is working absolutely fine the only and main thing which is not working proper is : the app is not showing the correct object name . for eg: the camera is focused on Laptop and it is displaying iy as a tree. Please help me how I can fix it.
My code:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'main.dart';
//import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
 _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
{
  bool isWorking = false;
  String result="";
  late CameraController cameraController;
  CameraImage? imgCamera;
  //late CameraImage imgCamera;

 loadModel() async
 {
   await Tflite.loadModel(
       model:"assets/model_unquant.tflite",
       labels:"assets/labels.txt",
   );
 }

  initCamera()
  {
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    cameraController.initialize().then((value)
        {
          if(!mounted)
          {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            cameraController.startImageStream((imageFromStream) =>
            {
              if(!isWorking)
                {
                  isWorking = true,
                  imgCamera = imageFromStream,
                  runModelOnStreamFrames(),

                }
            });
          });
        });
  }

  runModelOnStreamFrames() async
  {
    if(imgCamera != null)
      {
        var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
          bytesList:  imgCamera!.planes.map((plane)
          {
            return plane.bytes;
          }).toList(),

          imageHeight: imgCamera!.height,
          imageWidth: imgCamera!.width,
          imageMean: 127.5,
          imageStd: 127.5,
          rotation: 90,
          numResults: 2,
          threshold: 0.1,
          asynch:true,

        );
        result="";
        recognitions!.forEach((response)
        {
          result += response["label"] + " " + (response["confidence"] as double).toStringAsFixed(2) + "\n\n";
        });

        setState(() {
          result;
        });
        isWorking = false;
      }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    loadModel();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async
  {

    super.dispose();

    await Tflite.close();
    cameraController.dispose();//cameraController?.dispose();
  }

  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/jarvis.png")

              ),

            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
               Stack(
                 children: [
                   Center(
                     child:Container(
                       color: Colors.black,
                       height: 320,
                       width: 360,
                       child: Image.asset("assets/camera.png"),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Center(
                     child: TextButton(
                       onPressed: ()
                       {
                         initCamera();

                       },
                       child: Container(
                         margin: EdgeInsets.only( top: 35),
                         height: 270,
                         width: 360,
                         child: imgCamera == null
                             ? Container(
                           height: 330,
                           width:360,
                           child:Icon(Icons.photo_camera_front, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,size: 40,),
                         )
                             : AspectRatio(
                           aspectRatio:cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
                           child: CameraPreview(cameraController),

                         ),

                       ),
                     ),
                   ),

                 ],
               ),
             Center(
               child: Container(
                 margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.0),
                 child: SingleChildScrollView(
                   child:Text(
                     result,
                     style:TextStyle(
                       backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
                       fontSize: 30.0,
                       color: Colors.white,

                     ),
                   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                   )
                 )

               )
             )

              ],
            ),
          ), //img to background
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What was the machine learning you've used?

Comment: Supervised Learning - Image Classification